# Reducing space only within parenthesis

Tags: math-mode, spacing, catcodes

I would like to reduce the spacing around relation symbols *that appear within parenthesis* from thickmuskip to thinmuskip. Here is what I have come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newboolean{inpara}
\setboolean{inpara}{false}

\catcode`(=\active
\def({%
        \string(%
        \setboolean{inpara}{true}%
        }

\catcode`)=\active
\def){%
        \string)%
        \setboolean{inpara}{false}%
        }

\catcode`==\active
\def={%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{inpara}}{\,\mathord{\string=}\,}{\string=}%
        }
        
\begin{document}
    \[P(U_n) = \int_0^1\rho(c)\cdot P(U_n\mid C=c)\; \text{d}c\]
\end{document}
```

It needs to be improved in two ways:

1. So far it only works for `=`. I could add similar code for all the other relation symbols I use, but I would prefer a more elegant solution that modifies `\mathrel` itself. I don’t have the default definition of that command, though, and apperantly I don't understand how to use `\show`, for `\show\mathrel` produces a non-informative result.
2. It produces error messages in conjunction with the package xcolor. (That package is redundant in the MWE, but not in the actual document.)

Can anyone please help? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: I have no idea about your questions, but does your code work with `((a,b)=c)`? And what if you ever need to write a half-open interval `(0,1]`?

Comment: @WillieWong: No, it doesn't, but for the purpose of the document I'm working on it does not have to.

Comment: I believe you're asking an XY-question and that this would be much better treated with a syntax such as `\Pr{U_n}` for standard probability and `\Pr{U_n | C=c}` for conditional probability. It's not difficult to tailor the spacing around the bar in the second case to whatever you wish and to reduce the spacing around relation symbols in both parts.

Comment: Unrelated, but `\text{d}` is wrong and I'm not saying because it sometimes produces an upright “d” (which I hate, but that's not the point): if you want to ensure an upright “d” you want `\mathrm{d}`. Try `\text{d}` in the statement of a theorem, where the font is italic. Besides, `\;` is too wide and `\,` is more commonly employed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
\catcode`(=13
\def(#1){%
        \string(%
        \def\tmp{#1}\checkrightprimitive#1\end\right\end\relax
        \hbox{\thickmuskip=\thinmuskip$\tmp$}\doright)%
        }
\def\checkrightprimitive#1\right\end#2\relax{%
   \ifx\relax#2\relax \def\doright{}\else \def\tmp{#1}\def\doright{\right}\fi
}

$$
   a = b + (c=d)
$$
```

The new inline math mode is opened between brackets where `\thickmuslip` is set differently. The `\checkrightprimitive` macro checks if the `)` is preceded by `\right` and moves it after `\hbox`. This allows constructions `\left(...\right)`.

The macro does not work with nested brackets `(...(...)...)`, you have to write `(...{(...)}...)` in this case.

Second problem is that this macro does not respects math styles. But it can be solved using `\matchoice`.

Comment: Thank you! I had to add "\ifmmode ... \else\string(#1\string)\fi" to ensure that parenthesis in text mode were not affected, but then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do this with active characters is, as you've noticed, a recipe for some pain and suffering. Far better is to just create a macro that sets the parentheses and their contents with adjusted spacing. Untested prototype:

```
\newcommand{\pp}[1]{{
   \thickmuskip=\thinmuskip
   (#1)
}}

\[P(U_n) = \int_0^1\rho(c)\cdot P\pp{U_n\mid C=c}\; \text{d}c\]
```

**Update** As indicated in the comments, this won't work since you get one setting of `\thickmuskip` per math mode. If you were going to do this, you would instead need to use `\mbox` to escape out of math mode then return to math mode (perhaps using `\mathpalette` if you need to retain whether you were in super-/subscripts, display math etc.) and then set `\thickmuskip` in the inner math mode. egreg's solution at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594618/202780 provides another approach, specialized for `|`.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work - I think because \thickmuskip isn't "evaluated" until the end of the equation, at which point it will have reverted to its default definition. Also, I was hoping for something that could be implemented entirely in the preamble. Because I love pain and suffering.

Comment: As Casper says, this answer is wrong and does not do what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify `\mathrel`, because it is a TeX primitive that's not even entering the scene when the typesetting of `=` or another relation symbol is used.

You might think to make `=` (math) active and define it to issue `\modifiedmathrel{=}` (with a fantasy command `\modifiedmathrel` that adjusts the spacing, but, alas, this is not really possible.

Besides, if you need `P(A\mid x=(a+b)c)`, you'll be in trouble with nesting.

Since the application seems to be restricted to probabilities, here's a proposal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\Pr}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}r() }{%
  P(\makepr#1)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makepr}{mm}{%
  \reducespaces{#1}%
  \IfValueT{#2}{\,|\,\reducespaces{#2}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reducespaces}{m}{%
  \mathpalette\reducespacesaux{#1}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\reducespacesaux}{mm}{%
  \mbox{%
    \mathsurround=0pt
    \thickmuskip=\thinmuskip
    \medmuskip=1\thinmuskip minus 1\thinmuskip
    $#1#2$%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Pr(U_n) = \int_0^1\rho(c)\cdot \Pr(U_n | C=c)\,\mathrm{d}c
\]
\[
\Pr(A=B)\quad \Pr(A=B|C<D)\quad \Pr(A|x=(a+b)c)
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer `\Pr{...}`; in this case the first line of the magic code should be

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Pr}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{|}}m }{%
```